# How can I add some css properties to already existing ones?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to optimize my JavaScript code but I'm stuck.

I have two groups of CSS properties and respectively I have two JavaScript functions to act as they should - please check this demo:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xNbdvr

Each group represent different properties for body element.

In such case it's alright but I'm trying to figure out one universal function for that - I have something like this:

```js
function universal(color) {
  const selectedColor = color.value;
  const selectedProperty = color.name;
  const testSelection = document.querySelectorAll(`[name=${selectedProperty}`);

  for (let i = 0; i < testSelection.length; i++) {
    if (testSelection[i].checked) {
      document.body.style.cssText = `${selectedProperty}: ${selectedColor};`;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Background Color</p>
<input type="radio" id="red" value="red" name="background-color" onclick="universal(this)" checked/>
<label for="red">red</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="green" value="green" name="background-color" onclick="universal(this)" />
<label for="green">green</label>

<p>Color</p>
<input type="radio" id="blue" value="blue" name="color" onclick="universal(this)" checked/>
<label for="blue">blue</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="orange" value="orange" name="color" onclick="universal(this)" />
<label for="orange">orange</label>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xNbdJg

The problem is that it overwrites my CSS properties instead of adding them. I know that .style.cssText work like that so I need different solution for that problem.

The ideal solution would be such situation:

- under `selectedProperty` I have color/background-color (depends on group where I clicked)
- such code would be perfect: `document.body.style.selectedProperty = selectedColor;`

but of course I can't do that.

Do you know some way to use value stored under variable in such situation?

I hope it's understandable what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: will you use jquery.

Comment: There is no need in using jq - Heretic Monkey responded with a great article. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this to edit the CSS properties of the body, while keeping existing ones:

```
document.body.style[selectedProperty] = selectedColor
```

Full example below:

```js
function universal(color) {
  const selectedColor = color.value;
  const selectedProperty = color.name;
  const testSelection = document.querySelectorAll(`[name=${selectedProperty}`);

  for (let i = 0; i < testSelection.length; i++) {
    if (testSelection[i].checked) {
      document.body.style[selectedProperty] = selectedColor;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Background Color</p>
<input type="radio" id="red" value="red" name="background-color" onclick="universal(this)" checked/>
<label for="red">red</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="green" value="green" name="background-color" onclick="universal(this)" />
<label for="green">green</label>

<p>Color</p>
<input type="radio" id="blue" value="blue" name="color" onclick="universal(this)" checked/>
<label for="blue">blue</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="orange" value="orange" name="color" onclick="universal(this)" />
<label for="orange">orange</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just **add** a property that doesn't yet exist on the `document.body.style.cssText` you can try:

`document.body.style.cssText += "whatever-property: whatever-color;"`

Answer (score -1):

you can try by using jquery https://codepen.io/arindamx01/pen/8e54e55e231595ba7f4e01e5a0bf8351?editors=1010

```js
$('input').on('click', function(){
  $("input").each(function(){
   if( $(this).prop("checked")){
     var popCss = $(this).attr('name');
     var val = $(this).val();
     $('body').css(popCss, val);
   }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Background Color</p>
      <input type="radio" id="red" value="red" name="background-color" checked/>
      <label for="red">red</label><br>
      <input type="radio" id="green" value="green" name="background-color" />
      <label for="green">green</label>

      <p>Color</p>
      <input type="radio" id="blue" value="blue" name="color" checked/>
      <label for="blue">blue</label><br>
      <input type="radio" id="orange" value="orange" name="color" />
      <label for="orange">orange</label>
```